# How to get ActiveX recognised as add-on and allowed to run in IE11

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, windows-8, activex

Our web browser plugin has worked in all IE versions and still works fine in IE9 and IE10 but in IE11 the plugin is not even recognized and listed as an add-on. It's as if IE11 no longer supports ActiveX.

NOTE: this questions is asked as the developer of the plugin and not the end-user who might need to correct IE settings. So suggestions for how to detect ActiveX or how to adjust a browser settings to allow ActiveX are useless here.

We assume that what we need to do is make adjustments to the ActiveX structure so that IE11 on Windows 8 approves the plugin so that it can be available to the user at their discretion, ie: list it in the Add-on Manager.

A sample project and test page can be downloaded from here - http://addmine.com/temp/EPM_project.zip

Surely there is a workaround but what do we need to change?

Answer (score 0):

As of IE11, add-ons are supported only for IE on the desktop.  If you're running the Windows Store experience of IE, then your statement about IE11 not recognizing the plug-in is absolutely correct.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920753(v=vs.85).aspx) shows how you can have this experience prompt the user to open the page in the desktop experience of IE, which will support your plugin.

Having said that, it's entirely possible that you do change your plugin to support changes to the Windows 8 security model.  Here are a couple of links to get you started:

- [Supporting enhanced protected mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn519894(v=vs.85).aspx) (Note that this is part 1 of a four-part series)
- [IEInternals: Understanding Enhanced Protected Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx)
- [IE Blog: Enhanced protected mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/03/14/enhanced-protected-mode.aspx)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance